# Blender Render with shading layer

Tags: rendering

Hi all I started learning Blender and I want render image from shading layer but when render this image was good but with ball in corner what can I do to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

Thoose spheres are part of the Overlays section: you can turn off all overlays with the main button, or switch them on and off one by one in the dropdown panel.

[image]